# amavisd-new: fail (bad RSA signature)

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, amavis, iredmail

After installing IredMail on my Debian 9 server, I followed this tutorial to configure DKIM [Add new domain to iRedmail - with DKIM signature](http://oskarhane.com/add-new-domain-to-iredmail-with-dkim-signature/).

After following all the steps and running the `amavisd-new testkeys` command I get the following response:

First:

`TESTING#1 mydomin.com: dkim._domainkey.mydomin.com => fail (OpenSSL error: data too large for modulus)`

But if I run the command again, I get this other message:

`TESTING#1 mydomin.com: dkim._domainkey.mydomin.com => fail (bad RSA signature)`

Answer (score 0):

Now everything seems to be working.
For those who have the same problem:
All settings on the server are working.
As I'm using **CloudFlare** I had to add a new TXT record on the dns tab so things work out. That's the tip.